# Detecting cause of java app freezing

Tags: java, performance, latency

We have problem with our java application. Sometimes (once per several month) app pauses for 2-5 seconds. We notice this as loss of heartbeats for set of our network clients. And app log don't have any records during that freeze time span. GC logs don't show anything that could be the cause of application freeze for 5! seconds.

Brief application profile:

- Solaris with Solaris zones
- Java 1.6
- about 50 incoming and outgoing network connections (LBM over TCP/IP and UDP, JMS and JMX/RMI over TCP/IP),
- 3Gb memory,
- about 100+ threads

Could you suggest some tools/approaches that will allow us to identify root cause.

Comment: Wait, you're concerned about your application hanging for ~5 seconds once every few months?  I wouldn't even worry about it.

Comment: @JeffGohlke - What if deals with speed trading or any other extremely time-sensitive activities?

Comment: @PM77-1 I suppose you're right, that there would be a use-case where it's important.  I guess it just sounds trivial.

Comment: In similar cases start with _healthy_ source code: **FindBugs**. That can remove much indefinite behaviour (serialisation, concurrent initialisation and much more).

Comment: Have you completely ruled out `hardware` reasons like faulty network cards, routers, etc.?  Were you ever able to reproduce the problem in the controlled environment? Are all clients impacted randomly or is there a pattern?  Do you know for sure that it's just your application  and not the entire JVM "freeze"?

Comment: May be some rare deadlock condition in multi-threaded code, or something else happening in the OS outside of your code. Good luck, these are tough to find.  Try to figure out some similarities of each time it happens.

Comment: Which of 100+ threads slows down? What other threads slow down?

Comment: How to check thread slow downs and get overall picture of threads state at proper moment of app freeze? We see such kind of problems with app freeze once a month or two.